# Upcast, downcasting, and hiding methods in C++

Tags: c++, pure-virtual, downcast, upcasting

I'm writing a C++ library which needs to creates a complex object (D), but return to the user of my library a pointer to a simplified object (B) (hiding many of the methods of the complex object).  I have decided to implement this by returning a pointer to a simplified base class (B), and adding all of my complex functionality to a derived class (D) as follows:

```
class B {
  virtual void simple() = 0;
}

class D : public B {
  void simple() { cout << "visible simple stuff" ; }
  void complex() { cout << "invisible complex stuff" ; }
}
```

Internally I create my object D, but I return an upcast pointer as follows:

```
D Derived;
B *Bptr = &Derived;
return Bptr;
```

1. Is this the right way to hide functionality from the user, while making all of the additional functionality visible within the library?
2. Is hiding the .h file for class D the only way to prevent my library users from accessing the D methods?  (Downcasting back to a D class)  I will be releaseing the library  as open source, so the user of the library could access the D class definition.

Comment: User can only see `B` then the methods need to be pure virtual methods of `B` and implemented in `D`.  Look up _"interface"_ classes for C++.

Comment: _"I'm confused about what happens when a user of my library attempts:"_ Why be confused, when you can just pretend to be such a user, and test/answer your questions for yourself? You would quickly find that calling methods of `D` on a `B` is a syntax error, if it wasn't already obvious. And if you wanted these to be `virtual` methods, the result would be obvious from the basic rules of how virtual functions (must) work. I don't feel this question demonstrates sufficient basic research to be useful.

Comment: If you don’t allocate D on free store use a reference instead of a pointer a return value. If you allocate it on the free store use a unique_ptr.

Comment: I was looking for a deeper discussion (not yes it compiles) - I've rephrased

Comment: `Is hiding the .h file for class D` why do you have a .h file?

Comment: mani66: How does a unique_ptr protect the complex methods of D?  I have a .h for D because it is one of the classes inside my library.

Comment: @TSG "I was looking for a deeper discussion" And, yet, SO is not a forum, so "questions" that asks for discussions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About question **#1**: yes, if you provide a factory method along with your 'simple' interface:

```
class B {
public:
    static B * create();
    virtual void simple() = 0;
};
```

in B's implementation file (cpp):

```
B *B::create()
{
    return new D(); //or whatever 'hidden' implementation 
}
```

About your **#2**: hiding functionality means simplification in the first place, and is intended as a favour toward the library users, not a punishing constraint. So, hide the D class entirely and let the (good) users be happy with it.

Comment: Very cool - I didn't know B could create a D.  Since the factory returns a D object is it automatically upcast to a B ?

Comment: Yes it is. A pointer to B is all users can see, they know nothing about D (and don't want to know, trust me).